# Cesium - Label above the polyline

Tags: cesiumjs

it's possible to add Label above polyline in cesium library?

img: https://i.imgur.com/nLjEE0Q.jpg

Example: https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Hello%20World.html&label=Showcases&gist=329258ccdd84cb7a541eb246aa0fd8b3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this still an open issue in Cesium. So, you have to wait until they make it possible.

https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/53

https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/4108